# Dynamic function injection into Text::Template namespace

Tags: perl, texttemplate

I am using the following syntax to inject a function into [`Text::Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template) so it knows about that function when using `fill_in()`:

```
*Text::Template::GEN0::some_function = *SomeLibrary::some_function;
```

I noticed that if `fill_in()` is called more than once, that GEN0 changes to GEN1 for the subsequent call, then GEN2 ... etc.

So this only works if `fill_in` is called once, because only the GEN0 namespace is used.

How can I dynamically inject some_function into each used namespace?  I know it's something like this, but I don't know the syntax I would use exactly:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $item (@$items) {
    # *Text::Template::GEN{i}::some_function = *SomeLibrary::some_function;
    $i++;

    # Call fill_in here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to guess at the internals. Use the [PREPEND](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template#PREPEND-feature-and-using-strict-in-templates) option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Template;

sub MyStuff::foo { 'foo is not bar' };

my $tpl = Text::Template->new( 
                   TYPE => 'STRING',
                   SOURCE => "{ foo() }\n",
                   PREPEND => '*foo = \&MyStuff::foo',
                 );


print $tpl->fill_in;
```

Results in:

```
% perl tt.pl
foo is not bar
```

Comment: Thanks! Another reason it is necessary to do like this is because simply prepending the whole sub `sub my_sub {...}` causes all sorts of `sub already defined` errors because Text::Template has no option to append something only once. Seems like quite an oversight, unless I've missed it...

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $item (@$items) {
    my $str = "Text::Template::GEN${i}::some_function";
    no strict "refs";
    *$str = *SomeLibrary::some_function; 
    *$str if 0; # To silence warnings
    use strict "refs" 
    $i++;

    # Call fill_in here
}
```

Comment: I kept your `foreach` structure, but you can also replace it with `foreach my $i (0 .. $#items)` instead, so as to not keep a separate counter